# Analytic vs. Analytical

Tags: article-writing

I am trying write an article.

**Little Summary:**
I have developed some tools to analyze derivative of some function $f$. This characterization leads  to better results than previous works that only studied the function itself.

I am trying to say that:

"Our **analytic view** of the problem provides a better characterization of blah blah blah "

When I say  **analytic view** I mean that we not only look at a function but also its derivatives.

**My question:**

"Our **analytic view** of the problem provides a better characterization of blah blah blah "

**or**

"Our **analytical view** of the problem provides a better characterization of blah blah blah "

Comment: My guess is that in this context, "analytical" is to be preferred.  "Analytic" can *in general* be used as a synonym (in English) for "analytical", but "analytic function" is a term of art with a specific meaning that you may wish not to even connote, especially as you plan to examine derivatives of the function $f$.

Comment: analytical is for analysis, analytic is for having a power series ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you have doubts, most probably some other people will also have!**

It is always better to be clear, although it is sometimes a difficult decision where to stop (it depends on whether it is for a paper or for a book, whether it is for an abstract or introduction, etc, etc).

Summing up, much better something like: "By looking not only at the function itself but also at its derivatives, in contrast to what Mr.X did in [Y], we are able to provide a better characterization of".